# using for loop in jquery then pause between each iteration help

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop, delay, settimeout

How's it going,

Need some assistance, with some for loop and pausing. I did some research myself and I keep running into setTimeout() function but I need help understanding it more or if someone can help me out with how to implement it into my code or if there's another way.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            for(i=0; i<counter; i++)
            {
                dataCounter = i;
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'file.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {count: dataCounter},
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Error loading XML document');
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#contents").html(data);  
                    }
                });
            }

});
```

I would like to know how to pause after my $.ajax function before going on to my next increment.

Please help! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about...

```
(function() {

    var index = 0;

    function next() {

        setTimeout(function() {
            if (index == counter) {
                return;
            }

            // Do what you need to do   
            index++;
            next();
        }, 1000);

    }

})();
```

Alternatively, you can make a [sleep style function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/javascript-sleep) with `Date` and a `do { ... } while()` loop. But the `setTimeout()` is much better, because any JavaScript *sleep* style function has to sit around looping until it is ready to finish, which isn't really *sleeping*.

Comment: can I just copy the .ajax function into where you say // Do what you need to do, and this will work? Also, do I just put the (function() {...})(); all in the $(document).. sorry I'm fairly new to jquery.

Answer (score 2):

You mean "wait the request finish to send the next" ?

If so, set one more parameter in `.ajax` call.

```
async: false
```

From [jQuery .ajax doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> async :: Boolean - Default: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option
>   to false. Cross-domain requests and
>   dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note
>   that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the
>   request is active.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/hkjpA/

Hi andrewliu this example should work just fine, Hope that this help you